# VB6 Single event handler for multiple controls

Tags: vb6

I'm using the old VB6. What I'm trying to do is to find an easy way to handle a common event (e.g MouseDown/Up etc.) for all Controls on the Form. Controls are different and they should support that event (E.g. Controls like Edit\Grid\Button etc.). I tried something like:

```
...
Dim ctr As Control
For Each ctr In Me.Controls
       AddHandler ctr.MouseDown, AddressOf ControlMouseDownHandler
Next

....

Private Sub ControlMouseDownHandler()

End Sub
```

But I'm receiving Compile Error: - "Invalid use of AddressOf operator"

I prefer not to use Win32, but just what VB6 provides as functionality.

Any ideas are welcome

Comment: You can easily do this for controls of the *same* type using a control array, you cannot do this for mixed types.  Ther only way would be to subclass them all, capture the window message corresponding to the event and have it call the same WndProc you have defined.  You would then need additional plumbing to match the hwnd to the control instance.

Comment: Takes me back to having to write GotFocus and LostFocus handlers for every control just to highlight the field with focus, painful.  WHat processing are you looking to do in your shared event handler?  Could you create a set of UserControls based on the standard controls and add your common functionality in there?  Otherwise it is subclassing and I'd refer you to Matt Curland's Advanced VB book for how best to do that.

Comment: Hi and thanks for you attention :)
As I mentioned, the controls are not from same type. Therefore I cannot use ControlArray.  I'm not very good at VB6, but I think that it would be painful to create UserControls based on the standard controls or to try any other approach, which requires  to create custom class or whatever it is in VB for each different Control Type.

Comment: That is not VB6 code - it had no `AddHandler`

Comment: *I prefer not to use Win32, but just what VB6 provides as functionality.* I don't say this a lot but this is impossible